# How to compose an image using alpha_composite, but set the opacity of the mask?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have attached three different images, and I would like to create a composite that shows the BaseMap image with a `0.7` alpha radar  overlay, that is transparent otherwise, but the blue parts are `0.7` alpha, and the last image that will be `0.7` alpha as well.

These are example images, but I have to loop through an indefinite amount of them, and keep stacking them on the BaseMap always keeping it visible. I have tried `alpha_composite`, but I can not get the alpha for the mask and blend and paste renders the transparent parts of the radar and other image white.

Can someone help create a function that would pass in the full list of images and the BaseMap and it would layer them together as I mentioned?

[image: RDPS]
[image: Radar]
[image: BaseMap]

Comment: I fear that the Colab stuff, the Web Mapping stuff and base map stuff are not really germane to the issue. I think you'd be far more likely to get a sensible/helpful reply if you added 2-3 representative input images and the expected result to your question, along with your actual latest/greatest code rather than a link to some off-site resource.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your feedback, I have added example images and I hope you can help me solve but more importantly understand how to think about this issue sir.

Comment: It's still somehow unclear, how to blend the single images properly. I see two options here. [Option A] Fully blend radar image (middle) onto the red image (top). Blend that composite with alpha `0.7` onto the base image (bottom). [Option B] Blend red image with alpha `0.7` onto the base image. Blend radar image with alpha `0.7` onto that composite. Which one do you actually want? Results will definitely look different. Maybe, create the final desired output from the three given inputs using some image editing software (Photoshop, GIMP, ...)!?

Comment: I tried both options Mr. @HansHirse but the problem is that if I blend the red and radar image I lose the transperency of the radar and if I just stack them on top of each other the basemap gets lost in the background. Also there is no way to make the radar 0.7 alpha without adding a white film over the entire image.

Comment: Please make a mock-up of your expected result, using GIMP, Photoshop or even MS-Paint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will present some code for the two options I mentioned in the comments:

- Option A: Fully blend radar image onto the radar background image. Blend that composite with alpha `0.7` onto the base image.
- Option B: Blend radar background image with alpha `0.7` onto the base image. Blend radar image with alpha `0.7` onto that composite.

For generating alpha `0.7`, you can simply use [`point` operations](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#point-operations) in combination with [`Image.getchannel`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getchannel) and [`Image.putalpha`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putalpha). By doing so, you can later use `Image.alpha_composite` as-is.

```py
from PIL import Image

# Read images
basemap = Image.open('basemap.png').convert('RGBA')
radar_bg = Image.open('radar_bg.png').convert('RGBA')
radar = Image.open('radar.png').convert('RGBA')

# Option A: Fully blend radar image onto the radar background image.
# Blend that composite with alpha 0.7 onto the base image.
comp_a = Image.alpha_composite(radar_bg, radar)
comp_a.putalpha(comp_a.getchannel('A').point(lambda x: x * 0.7))
comp_a = Image.alpha_composite(basemap, comp_a)
comp_a.save('comp_a.png')

# Option B: Blend radar background image with alpha 0.7 onto the base
# image. Blend radar image with alpha 0.7 onto that composite.
radar_bg.putalpha(radar_bg.getchannel('A').point(lambda x: x * 0.7))
radar.putalpha(radar.getchannel('A').point(lambda x: x * 0.7))
comp_b = Image.alpha_composite(Image.alpha_composite(basemap, radar_bg), radar)
comp_b.save('comp_b.png')
```

That's the composite from option A:

[image: Option A]

And, that's the composite from option B:

[image: Option B]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.3
Pillow:        8.3.1
----------------------------------------
```